# Splitting an EPS

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

I have an EPS file containing a load of icons. Is there any way I can export each individual shape in the file to a PNG? It's difficult to work with a number of EPS files because I don't see thumbnails in explorer. I have both Illustrator and Photoshop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could technically open EPS files with Photoshop, but this would rasterize the graphics. Because of this, **Illustrator** is a better option.

If your image has the icons sorted in a grid, you could just draw slices and export them that way.

***Using Slices***

There are a few ways to create slices from elements:

- Select one or more objects on the artboard, and choose Object > Slice > Make.
- Select the Slice tool  and drag over the area where you want to create a slice. Shift-drag to constrain the slice to a square. Alt‑drag (Windows) or Option-drag (Mac OS) to draw from the center.
- Select one or more objects on the artboard, and choose Object > Slice > Create From Selection.
- Place guides where you want to slice the artwork, and choose Object > Slice > Create From Guides.
- Select an existing slice, and choose Object > Slice > Duplicate Slice.

Then you just need to save the result as PNG using `Save For Web & Devices`.

<sub>(Source: [Adobe Help](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-636ca.html))</sub>

***Using Layers and Scripts***

You could also use a script like this one: [Export Illustrator Layers as PNGs](http://www.ericson.net/content/2010/10/export-layers-as-pngs/).